Define EPSG transformation code on command line with cs2cs
When using cs2cs for a one line transformation on the command line, I wish to use the EPSG code to define the transformation though have not yet worked out how to do it. The best I have achieved is to define the area, when really I want to fix it to EPSG:1613.
echo 58 5 | cs2cs EPSG:4230 EPSG:4326 -f "%0.11f" --area EPSG:2334

This leads to me to another issue, in that when I look for the transformation by key word it does not come up:
echo 58 5 | cs2cs EPSG:4230 EPSG:4326 -f "%0.11f" --area "Norway - offshore"
Several candidates area of use matching provided name :
  EPSG:2332 : Norway - offshore north of 65°N. Also Svalbard.
  EPSG:2333 : Norway - offshore between 62°N and 65°N and west of 5°E.
  EPSG:2601 : Norway - offshore north of 62°N. Also Svalbard - onshore and offshore.

If I then try a more generic search it can be found as EPSG:2334 : Norway - offshore south of 62°N - North Sea.:
echo 58 5 100 | cs2cs EPSG:4230 EPSG:4326 -f "%0.11f" --area "Norway -"
Several candidates area of use matching provided name :
  EPSG:1352 : Norway - onshore.
  EPSG:1741 : Norway - west of 3°30'W of Oslo (7°13'22.5"E of Greenwich).
  EPSG:1742 : Norway - between 3°30'W and 1°10' W of Oslo (7°13'22.5"E and 9°33'22.5"E of Greenwich).
  EPSG:1743 : Norway - between 1°10'W and 1°15'E of Oslo (9°33'22.5"E and 11°58'22.5"E of Greenwich).
  EPSG:1744 : Norway - between 1°15'E and 4°20'E of Oslo (11°58'22.5"E and 15°03'22.5"E of Greenwich).
  EPSG:1745 : Norway - between 4°20'E and 8°10'E of Oslo (15°03'22.5"E and 18°53'22.5"E of Greenwich).
  EPSG:1746 : Norway - between 8°10'E and 12°10'E of Oslo (18°53'22.5"E and 22°53'22.5"E of Greenwich).
  EPSG:1747 : Norway - between 12°10'E and 16°15'E of Oslo (22°53'22.5"E and 26°58'22.5"E of Greenwich).
  EPSG:1748 : Norway - east of 16°15'E of Oslo (26°58'22.5"E of Greenwich).
  EPSG:2332 : Norway - offshore north of 65°N. Also Svalbard.
  EPSG:2333 : Norway - offshore between 62°N and 65°N and west of 5°E.
  EPSG:2334 : Norway - offshore south of 62°N - North Sea.
  EPSG:2344 : Finland and Norway - onshore.
  EPSG:2601 : Norway - offshore north of 62°N. Also Svalbard - onshore and offshore.
  EPSG:3636 : Norway - onshore - west of 6°E.
  EPSG:3639 : Norway - onshore - between 6°E and 7°E.
  EPSG:3647 : Norway - onshore - between 7°E and 8°E.
  EPSG:3648 : Norway - onshore - between 8°E and 9°E.
  EPSG:3649 : Norway - onshore - between 9°E and 10°E.
  EPSG:3650 : Norway - onshore - between 10°E and 11°E.
  EPSG:3651 : Norway - onshore - between 11°E and 12°E.
  EPSG:3653 : Norway - onshore - between 12°E and 13°E.
  EPSG:3654 : Norway - onshore - between 13°E and 14°E.
  EPSG:3655 : Norway - onshore - between 14°E and 15°E.
  EPSG:3656 : Norway - onshore - between 15°E and 16°E.
  EPSG:3657 : Norway - onshore - between 16°E and 17°E.
  EPSG:3658 : Norway - onshore - between 17°E and 18°E.
  EPSG:3660 : Norway - onshore - between 18°E and 19°E.
  EPSG:3661 : Norway - onshore - between 19°E and 20°E.
  EPSG:3662 : Norway - onshore - between 20°E and 21°E.
  EPSG:3663 : Norway - onshore - between 21°E and 22°E.
  EPSG:3665 : Norway - onshore - between 22°E and 23°E.
  EPSG:3667 : Norway - onshore - between 23°E and 24°E.
  EPSG:3668 : Norway - onshore - between 24°E and 25°E.
  EPSG:3669 : Norway - onshore - between 25°E and 26°E.
  EPSG:3671 : Norway - onshore - between 26°E and 27°E.
  EPSG:3672 : Norway - onshore - between 27°E and 28°E.
  EPSG:3673 : Norway - onshore - between 28°E and 29°E.
  EPSG:3674 : Norway - onshore - between 29°E and 30°E.
  EPSG:3676 : Norway - onshore - east of 30°E.
  EPSG:4066 : Norway - onshore - between 6°E and 12°E.
  EPSG:4067 : Norway - onshore - between 12°E and 18°E.
  EPSG:4068 : Norway - onshore - between 18°E and 24°E.
  EPSG:4069 : Norway - onshore - between 24°E and 30°E.
  EPSG:4656 : Norway - inshore and nearshore.
  ESRI:19 : Norway - onshore - 4.68~E to 12~E
  ESRI:20 : Norway - Baerum Kommune
  ESRI:21 : Norway - Bergenhalvoen Kommune
  ESRI:22 : Norway - Oslo Kommune

Of course if I then search for that nothing comes up:
echo 58 5 100 | cs2cs EPSG:4230 EPSG:4326 -f "%0.11f" --area "Norway - offshore south of 62°N - North Sea"
No area of use matching provided name

Using projinfo I can list all available transformations and find the one I want which is 'Operation 18' (For clarity I have not listed the entire output).
projinfo -s EPSG:4230 -t EPSG:4326 --spatial-test intersects

Operation No. 18:
EPSG:1613, ED50 to WGS 84 (24), 1.0 m, Norway - offshore south of 62°N - North Sea.
PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad
  +step +proj=push +v_3
  +step +proj=cart +ellps=intl
  +step +proj=helmert +x=-90.365 +y=-101.13 +z=-123.384 +rx=0.333 +ry=0.077
        +rz=0.894 +s=1.994 +convention=position_vector
  +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84
  +step +proj=pop +v_3
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1

My understanding is that I can put the full pipeline on the command line (albeit somewhat unwieldy), but can I not just use the EPSG transformation code in the same way as defining a transformer when using pyproj?

I guess that you want this, right?
projinfo -k operation EPSG:1613 -o proj --single-line -q
+proj=pipeline +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad +step +proj=push +v_3 +step +proj=cart +ellps=intl +step +proj=helmert +x=-90.365 +y=-101.13 +z=-123.384 +rx=0.333 +ry=0.077 +rz=0.894 +s=1.994 +convention=position_vector +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=pop +v_3 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1

or more readable (not in a single line)
projinfo -k operation EPSG:1613 -o proj
PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad
  +step +proj=push +v_3
  +step +proj=cart +ellps=intl
  +step +proj=helmert +x=-90.365 +y=-101.13 +z=-123.384 +rx=0.333 +ry=0.077
        +rz=0.894 +s=1.994 +convention=position_vector
  +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84
  +step +proj=pop +v_3
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1

So finally you can concatenate
echo 58 5 0 | cct $( projinfo -k operation EPSG:1613 -o proj --single-line -q )
 57.9994135424    4.9985284125        0.0000           inf

